# How to echo specific value from associative array in <select> for Selected attribute

Tags: php, html, css

can anyone help me out for this thing

```
$person = array(‘abb’ => ‘Abbie, ‘abi’ => ‘Abigail’, ade’ => ‘Adelaide’);
$selection = '';
foreach ($selection as $abbreviation => $name) {
    $selection = $selection."<option value=$abbreviation selected=(HOW DO I ECHO Abigail HERE FOR DEFAULT OPTION)>$name</option>";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
    $person = array('abb' => 'Abbie', 'abi' => 'Abigail', 'ade' => 'Adelaide');
$selection = '<select>';
foreach ($person as $abbreviation => $name) {
    $selection = $selection.'<option value="'.$abbreviation.'"';
    if($name=='Abigail')
        $selection .= 'selected';
    $selection .=  ">$name</option>";
}
$selection .= '</select>';
echo $selection;
```

if i understand right, this is what you want

Comment: Its just selected the but not print on select for drop down

Comment: sorry i don't understand, can you explain a little more?

Comment: If you want it not to specifically select 'Abigail', but choose whatever name to select programmatically, replace the string 'Abigail' with a `$var` of your own, within the 'if statement', which will be selected.  We don't understand your question, and replies like 'It's not working' won't help you get your question answered.